# How to connect overlapping VNets in Azure?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I am working on an Azure-based networking solution.

[image]

We have a typical hub and spoke VNets topology. The Hub VNet connects to on-prem DC via ExpressRoute and spoke VNets peer to Hub VNet. There is an Azure Firewall in the Hub that filters traffic between Hub-spokes and hub-on-prem segments. GREEN in the diagram

We have a bizarre requirement of adding a new isolated VNet (RED in the diagram) that will have overlapping IPs with the existing network (GREEN). We want to allow workloads in this new VNet to access private apps deployed in Hub or on-prem.

I need help on how to achieve this connectivity.

**Note: We don't want to set up any VPN between the new VNet and Hub**

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, I may miss one information here but how do you consider the new isolated vnet to join the corp network, VPN with on-prem ?

Answer (score 1):

As you might appreciate, this is more of a general networking limitation moreso than an Azure limitation. If we want two different networks with overlapping IP addresses to communicate then we would need networking devices in between both networks that perform some form of network address translation so the IP addresses *appear* to be different to the communicating hosts. Below is an example from the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-overview)

[image: Azure VPN NAT]

Logically you have two options here:

- Create your own network devices and configure routes between these subnets to transit your virtual appliance that does the translation.
- Use the managed service from Azure. In this case, it's the Azure VPN Gateway

I saw your note above for not wanting to use any VPN devices. Having said that, however, generally speaking it is usually a better option from an availability & supportability perspective to leverage the built-in offering vs. hand rolling your own virtual appliance using IP tables or a Windows NAT Router or something similar. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to peer Virtual Networks with overlapping IP addresses. This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#can-i-peer-two-vnets-with-matching-or-overlapping-address-ranges). You will have to move to a different address space and   move/recreate resources under this new address space.
If it helps you can take a look at this [Checklist before moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#checklist-before-moving-resources).